# How to debug (and fix) Symfony2|3 routes?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-routing

I have this routes defined at `app/config/routing.yml` in a Symfony 2.8 app:

```
platform_chat:
    resource: "@PlatformChatBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /chat

platform_admin:
    resource: "@PlatformAdminBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /admin

#----> this is part of routing.yml but I forgot to add it
easy_admin_bundle:
    resource: "@PlatformAdminBundle/Controller/AdminController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /admin

#FOSUser
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

As you may already notice `PlatformAdminBundle` is the backend and `PlatformChatBundle` is the frontend. Having that in mind I am tryin to setuo and use one firewall for both and then on `security.interactive_login` event redirect to right route|path. This is how the firewall looks like:

```
security:
    ...
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_CHATTER:     ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    ...
    firewalls:
        ...
        ignored:
            pattern: ^/(login(_check)?|logout|resetting)$
            security: false
        global:
            pattern: ^/admin/(.*)|^/chat/(.*)
            provider: fos_userbundle
            form_login:
                csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                # if true, forward the user to the login form instead of redirecting
                use_forward: true
                # login success redirecting options (read further below)
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: /admin
                target_path_parameter: _target_path
                use_referer: true
                remember_me: true
            logout: ~
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/chat/, role: ROLE_CHATTER }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

But it's not working because when I try to login as either user I end with this error:

> You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration.

Which makes me think that routes or firewall aren't properly configured. I have checked the routes under debug toolbar and none matches so they are wrong complete. I have read docs [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) but it's not helpful at all and I am not getting the fix for the problem. You can take this post as a *second part* of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756244/how-to-create-two-chat-and-admin-or-more-secured-areas-with-fosuserbundle) but I don't want to change the topic of the old one and neither the content because I think it will be helpful on the future for somebody else. So, any advice guys? What would you debug this kind of issues related to routes? Any fix for my particular problem? I am really stuck here!

**Update**

I have made the changes as @xabbuh suggested so now `app/config/routing.yml` looks like:

```
platform_chat:
    resource: "@PlatformChatBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /chat
    options:
            expose: true

platform_admin:
    resource: "@PlatformAdminBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /admin
    options:
        expose: true

#EasyAdminBundle
easy_admin_bundle:
    resource: "@PlatformAdminBundle/Controller/AdminController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /admin
    options:
        expose: true

#FOSUser
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

#FOSUser Groups
fos_user_group:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/group.xml"
    prefix: /group

#FOSJsRouting
fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"
```

and `` looks like:

```
security:
    ...
    firewalls:
        ...
        global:
            pattern: /
            anonymous: true
            provider: fos_userbundle
            form_login:
                csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                use_forward: true # if true, forward the user to the login form instead of redirecting
                always_use_default_target_path: true # login success redirecting options (read further below)
                default_target_path: /admin
                target_path_parameter: _target_path
                use_referer: true
                remember_me: true
            logout: ~
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/chat/, role: ROLE_CHATTER }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

after clear the cache  here are my tries and results:

- Login as `ROL_CHATTER`: I am going to `http://domain.tld/app_dev.php/chat/` as expected I get the login form and using valid credentials I get the following message: *Access Denied. You are CHATTER*. This is right because I have a listener on `security.interactive_login` and that is what I am doing when user login with those creds.
- Login as `ROL_ADMIN`: I am going to `http://domain.tld/app_dev.php/admin/` as expected I get the login form and using valid credentials I get the following message: *Bad credentials*. This is wrong because credentials are valid and at least I should get another message (*Access Denied. You are ADMIN*) because the listener on `security.interactive_login` but as I said this is not what is happening.

Info related to the listener is on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756244/how-to-create-two-chat-and-admin-or-more-secured-areas-with-fosuserbundle). What's wrong?

Comment: What is the path associated with the `fos_user_security_check` route?

Comment: @xabbuh no matches with that path, see [this pic](http://content.screencast.com/users/ReynierPM/folders/Snagit/media/4a80a237-edba-4cda-94e7-5841dce3b57f/01.15.2016-15.08.png)

Comment: Even in your former post you had that `BadCredentialsException` so I think that something is wrong with your admin user or you handle it. Try to debug your problem by inspecting the stack trace and see where the exception is actually thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that the regex used to match requests for the `global` firewall is `/admin/(.*)|^/chat/(.*)`, but your check path is `/login_check`. As you can see that path would not be matched by your firewall which leads to the error message you posted.

If I were you, I would simply drop the firewall fore the login related stuff and change the regex for the `global` firewall to `/`. You would then only have to add `anonymous: true` so that users that are not logged in would be able to access the login form. Access to your protected areas would still be denied by your access control section.

Comment: @malcolm I can't make this to work and I am asking to xabbuh if have some free time to check my sources? I can share through Bitbucket, could you?

Comment: @xabbuh give me your Bitbucket user so I can give you permissions on sources

Comment: Also see my edit a minute ago, perhaps this is the problem and I am not aware

Comment: My Bitbucket username is the same, but please make the changes I suggested in my answer.

Comment: I have made the changes as you suggested, is on the repo already

Comment: See my update at OP, there is the *weird* issue I am having